# how can I sniff packets in https websites using scapy module in python3?

Tags: python-3.x

I wrote this program:

```
import scapy.all as scapy
from scapy.layers import http


def sniff(interface):
    scapy.sniff(iface=interface, store=False, prn=process_sniffed_packet)


def process_sniffed_packet(packet):
    if packet.haslayer(http.HTTPRequest):
        url = packet[http.HTTPRequest].Host + packet[http.HTTPRequest].Path
        url = url.decode("utf-8")
        print(url)


sniff("Wi-Fi")
```

it works well with http websites and capture packets and urls, but when I run this program and open a https website in my browser it does not work and does not show me any packets and urls, I want to know what changes should I made in this code that this code can work on https websites like http

Comment: The reason we use an encrypted communication channel like https is *explicitly* to prevent this sort of sniffing. [This answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/83039/27680) over on security.stackexchange.com has a reasonable answer to this question.